# Remote access to MySQL works from an external PC but not from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect from an external network (from my work) PC with C# to MySQL.
MySQL is working in a PC at home.

From Work PC I can have access by browser to MySQL without problem.

I enter to mysql by this kind of address: `http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:30001/phpmyadmin/`.  Then I enter the user root and password, Works OK!

Ports for apache: 443,30001
Ports for mysql:  3006

In MySQL I have done:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'rootPass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The answer I get from C# when I try to connect:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Any idea?  Thanks!

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.Server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:30001"; //I have checked only the ip aswell:  "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    builder.UserID = "root"; 
    builder.Password = "xxxxxx"; 
    builder.Port = 3306;
    builder.Database = "testremoto";
}
```

Comment: "ports for mysql: 3006", why you try to use another port?

Comment: builder.Server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:30001" doesn't make sense, remove the :30001

Comment: If access via a URL where is that URL served from the same PC?? something else inside your home network? if your web server is on 30001 it would seem unlikely thats the port for mysql

Comment: The port number does not matter. You should make sure that your home PC is accessible from the WAN side. Try telnetting to your MySQL port and watch with netstat if a connection is established. Or use a MySql frontend like HeidiSql or similar.

Comment: Maybe your Mysql doesn't allow connections from other IP. See your mysql config info. It should be bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Comment: Thank you to everyone, I have made some test with your comment without success.  :(